# Auto resize NSCollectionViewItem to fit screen

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I'm trying to create a NSCollectionView where it's items adapt to the available space rather than defining a fixed size for the items and resize the NSCollectionView accordingly.

I couldn't figure out a way to achieve that with the NSCollectionViewFlowLayout as it requires a fixed size for it's items. I came quite close to the desired result with the NSCollectionViewGridLayout. However I need the CollectionViewItems to keep their aspect ratio (squares) when scaling the window that contains the NSCollectionView, while the GridLayout scales the items accordingly to their min and maxItemSize. Depending on the window size and the number of items in the collection I end up with items that are not exactly squares.

Example screenshot: [distorted NSCollectionViewItems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFn36.png)

I could probably work around that with setting the maximumNumberOfColumns in the grid, depending on the number of items in the collection and the window size, however it seems to be a bit cumbersome. Is there a better way to achieve the desired layout? Maybe with a custom NSCollectionViewLayout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the following protocol in your controller:

```
NSCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

It has a lot of methods allowing fine-tuning items (size / position / margins). Dont forget to set your collection view layout to be "flow" (in IB).

Look for implementing the following methods:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: NSCollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> NSEdgeInsets {

   ...

}

func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: NSCollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSSize {

   ...
}

func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: NSCollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That would mean to calculate the size of the cells depending on the window size and the amount of items, right? There is no 'auto-layout' for that?

Comment: Correct. There is no auto layout for such details. I wish they made it a bit more CSS-flexbox looking.